# Execution stuck while parallilize and repartition 1 million number in spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I am New To scala. I am very stuck on this point.

**See simple example :**
I have 320 gb of RAM and 4 nodes . But still if I execute below code on 1 million data. then execution stucks at same point.

> matchingRowsPOI contain array of 1 million numbers.

Using below code I am creating pairs . like `(1,2),(1,3) (2,3)` etc.

```
val totalPairsForDistrict1 = sc.parallelize(matchingRowsPOI,200).flatMap(x => {
      matchingRowsPOI.filter(_ > x).map((x, _))
    }).repartition(200)

totalPairsForDistrict1 .count
```

But If I execute this code then Execution stop at same place for many hours.
I have check it on UI. It does not process at all. I am not understanding why this is happening.

Is it because memory is not sufficient to execute this operation or what ?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is very crucial problem for me.Can someone explain me Why this is happening.

Comment: According to your code, there is no action to actually execute your transformations.
You need to call an action on totalPairsForDistrict1 , such as collect , count, saveAsTextFile.

Comment: @tauitdnmd Sorry I forgot to add it in code. Please check updated code.

Comment: You are using parallelize with 200 partition and then again using repartition which might be causing issue. please try to run by removing repartition.